# Load different UI for different devices in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am new to Native script with Angular2. I am developing application for Tablet and Mobile devices. I want to load different UI (html) files for different devices. I created four files like,

```
1) test.html
2) test.minWH320.html
3) test.minWH480.html
4) test.minWH600.html
5) test.minWH700.html
```

But it is loading test.html file for all devices
 Can anybody help me..Please

Comment: What does 'is not working' mean? The question needs clear problem statement and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , otherwise it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to bootstrap your app according to screen size i:e use `@media queries`. which will load the page with a different layout for different screens.

More on [`media queries`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

**Angular a.k.a one framework** ticks a lot of boxes when comes to out of the box support for mobile devices

Comment: Media queries are not supported in NativeScript, I think.

Comment: Hi Rahul Singh. Thanks for replay. But Media queries are not working in Native script